# Openvpn not routing to the internet over a tun interface

Tags: linux, networking, routing, openvpn, nat

I've set up openvpn using tun. I can ping both ways between client & server. But I can't ping from the client to 8.8.4.4 (as a test).

I've added nat with:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

But things don't appear to route from the tun0 interface to eth0.

`tcpdump` on `tun0` shows that packets are coming in (in this case ping to 8.8.4.4 as a test):

```
12:21:55.956564 IP 10.8.0.10 > google-public-dns-b.google.com: ICMP echo request, id 512, seq 17153, length 40
```

But `tcpdump` on `eth0` doesn't show anything other than my ssh traffic.

I have a ping looping from the vpn client, and I see that in my `tcpdump` on `tun0`, but I don't see anything "google" in my `tcpdump` on `eth0`.

Any thoughts? I can run this ping fine from the openvpn host. iptables are empty except for the MASQUERADE action, with defaults to accept.

Comment: I agree with poige. Paste routes, iptables rules, tcpdump on eth0, openvpn configs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, it was step #1 in this guide on configuring linux as a router... turn on IP Forwarding.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-as-router-for-dsl-t1-line-etc.html

Answer (score 0):

Iptables -A FORWARD -j ACCEPT?

Comment: Policy is accept by default: Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

Answer (score 0):

Why `-j MASQUERADE` @ `-o eth0` if you're talking bout I've set up openvpn using *tun*?

You need to verify you've got: routing (forwarding, actually) enabled (sysctl), routing is properly set-up (needed routes are installed), NAT is properly set-up if it's needed.

Comment: Because he intend to SNAT vpn clients -> internet?

Comment: I'm guessing I'm missing a route here. What do I need to do to route traffic out the default gateway? I'm confused here because I already have a default route, so I am assuming that any packet that comes in destine for an external address will be forwarded to the default gateway.

Comment: Have you verified you have forwarding enabled?…